# how to get list of all available images for a region in amazon web services using aws-java-sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-java-sdk

How can i get the list of all available images for a region using aws-java-sdk, I just tried with the below code, it is keep on executing for a long time.

```
AmazonEC2  ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(awsCredetials);
ec2Client.setRegion(RegionUtils.getRegion("us-west-2"));
DescribeImagesRequest request = new DescribeImagesRequest().withFilters(new LinkedList<Filter>());
DescribeImagesResult describeImagesResult= ec2Client.describeImages(request);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are listing all public AMIs in us-west-2, there are over 50,000, add some filters.

for example to find all 64bit Ubuntu AMIs:

```
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("architecture").withValues("x86_64"));
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("platform").withValues("Ubuntu"));
```

See the complete list of filters [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html).

Comment: can u please share me some samples, if possible please

Comment: @MohamedUvaisM added an example

Answer (score 0):

When I tried with filter

```
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("architecture").withValues("x86_64"));
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("platform").withValues("Ubuntu"));
```

I got zero result and the reason I found was like `platform` is always `null` apart from `windows`.
I have tried with wildcards

```
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("architecture").withValues("x86_64"));
request.getFilters().add(new Filter().withName("description").withValues("*Linux*"));
```

which works well since we are not bothering about `plarform` here. But hardly I don't know why `DescribeImagesResult` returns `platform` as `null` for `OS` apart from windows